# AVG and Adaware saying it cant detect my internet settings but I am online

Tags: windows-vista, internet-connection, avg-antivirus

Hi I am trying to install AVG but it is saying it can't detect my internet connection but I'm clearly online. I just recently disabled some startup sevices and programs any idea if some box I unchecked is causing AVG  and Adaware to not be able to detect my settings.

Comment: Are you trying to deal with some sort of Malware infection? Some will mess with connection settings

Comment: Can you enable the startup items you disabled? That seems the obvious place to start.

Comment: If all else fails do a Windows System Restore, pick a date before things got wonky.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your personal software firewall isn't blocking the update process.  If you can get to the internet through your normal browser then your internet is working, and the issue is likely a firewall blocking the update.  I recommend disabling your firewall, trying it again.

If that solves the problem then add an exception to your firewall.  (Remember that windows also has a firewall built in).